# select data from couple of subqueries in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have problem with mysql
I need to select sums from some joined tables but I dont get the result I need.
here's my query.

```
SELECT kelas.kelas as kelas, perpus.perpus as perpus
    FROM
    (SELECT b.id_alt, SUM(a.nilai_crips) AS kelas FROM crips AS a JOIN list AS b ON a.id_crips=b.id_crips where a.id_kriteria=34 group by b.id_alt
    )as Kelas,
    (SELECT SUM(a.nilai_crips) AS perpus FROM crips AS a JOIN list AS b ON a.id_crips=b.id_crips where a.id_kriteria=35 group by b.id_alt
    )as perpus
    group by kelas.id_alt
```

the 1st column shows the right result but the second column doesn't.

```
kelas | perpus
100   | 100
100   | 100
100   | 100
100   | 100
10    | 100
100   | 100
80    | 100
100   | 100
```

if I deleted the 1st subquery, the the column would return the right result.

```
perpus
100
100
100
100
100
100
100
76
```

what is wrong with my query? thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You are doing cross join between the two subquery result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single SELECT, and conditionally add the values:

```
SELECT 
    b.id_alt, 
    SUM(IF(a.id_kriteria = 34,a.nilai_crips,0)) AS kelas,
    SUM(IF(a.id_kriteria = 35,a.nilai_crips,0)) AS perpus
FROM crips AS a 
JOIN list AS b 
ON a.id_crips = b.id_crips 
WHERE a.id_kriteria IN (34,35)
GROUP BY b.id_alt;
```